# Custom jQuery validation

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying jQuery validate. My code is:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("isOnlyEmail", function(value, element,param) { 
  var emailVal;
    $.getJSON('get/getAllData.php?operation=email&email='+value, null, function(data) {
       alert(data);
       if(data==0)
          emailVal true;
       else
          emailVal false;
    });
    return emailVal;
  }, "My message");
```

I want to display my message, if only return value is true. but this code is wrong. My message is displayed continuously.

if I change my code as follows:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("isOnlyEmail", function(value, element,param) { 

        return false;

      }, "My message");
```

my message is displayed.

if I change my code as follows:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("isOnlyEmail", function(value, element,param) { 

            return true;

          }, "My message");
```

my message is not displayed.

Any idea?

**HTML code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap jQuery plugins compiled and minified -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                jQuery.validator.addMethod("isOnlyEmail", function(value, element,param) { 
                    var emailVal;

                    $.getJSON('get/getAllData.php?operation=email&email='+value, null, function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        if(data==0)
                            emailVal true;
                        else
                            emailVal false;
                    });
                    return emailVal;
                }, "My Message");

                $("#signupform").validate({
                    rules:{
                        email:"isOnlyEmail"
                    },

                    highlight: function(label) {
                        $(label).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success');
                        $(label).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
                    },
                success: function(label) {
                    label
                    .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                    .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error')
                    .closest('.control-group').addClass('success');
                }
            });
        });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email@site.com" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP Code**:

```
<?php

    require_once("../db/dbconnect.php");

    $operation = $_GET['operation'];

    if($operation == "email"){

        $mail=$_GET['email'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE email='".$mail."'";
        $result = execute_query($query);
        echo mysql_num_rows($result);
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: did you try debugging in Firebug?

Comment: yes I've tried. .getJSON() function is working correctly.

Comment: Please post the rest of the code... the HTML for the form and the rest of the jQuery.

Comment: If your test reveals that `true` does not display your message and `false` displays your message, then why are you wanting `true` to display messages?  Just switch them in your logic.

Comment: My goal is that: if currently entered email address is already used before, display "my message".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem is solved.

I change  my code as follows:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("isOnlyEmail", function(value, element) { 
   var emailVal=true;
   $.ajax({
       url: 'get/getAllData.php?operation=email&email='+value,
       type:'GET',
       dataType: 'json',
       async: false,
       success: function (data) {
            if(data==0)
               emailVal=true;
            else
               emailVal=false;
            },

        });   
   return emailVal;
}, "My Message");
```

Normally, ajax call is run asynchronous mode. There is due to the asynchronous mode, it does not work. If  "async: false" is added in my code, the problem is solved.